# What is a balanced version of this magical vending machine?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, potions

One of my players (lvl 7) wants to buy/commission a magical vending machine that produces healing potions. I like the idea, but don't want it to break the game. For 1000-1500gp, what are some reasonable limitations for the item?

Maybe something like non-permanence for the potions, or random fails each time it is invoked (or maybe each time the potion is actually drank)?

Comment: What level are your players at? As stands this question may be too broad as there are many many possible "limitations". Perhaps the machine breaks, or some potions are fake, or it has an upkeep, or the potions heal less than standard ones... However I may be incorrect in my assumption here

Comment: This particular group is lvl 7-8, but I intentionally left it open-ended, so various answers/limitations could apply to different groups.

Comment: Unfortunately, such open-ended idea generation questions are not a good fit for our site; all answers may be equally valid, and there's no way to choose a single "best" answer. [Such questions might be better suited to a forum.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) You might also be able to improve the question by narrowing your question down to include specific criteria (beyond just "I don't want it to break the game").

Comment: You should probably try and propose a solution and then ask "Is this Balanced?" That way there will be a definite answer (Yes, No, Maybe, etc) and discussion can be generated from that point.

Comment: See [how to ask a good homebrew review question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8122/48759) it might be a good start for the kind of homebrew questions that work well here. If you have mechanics for this item, give them in the question and we can provide feedback regarding balance and effects it may have on your game.

Answer (score 4):

### The potions only last 24 hours

Effectively this gives them access to one potion (50gp) per day on a use it or lose it basis - that's not going to break anyone's game.

That said, you could just let it be a wand that cures 1/day directly and cut out the middleman.